# Difference between Logistic Regression and Decision Trees

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression, decision-tree

I was Studying Decision Trees and understood that it generally is used in Classification Problems.
But the Logistic Regression is also used in Classification Problems only.

So I searched everywhere on the internet but didn't got any satisfying results. I am really confused when should we use what or give me some use cases where either of any works better

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between logistic regression and decision trees is that logistic regression models the relationship between the predictor variables and the outcome variable as a linear function, while decision trees create a hierarchical tree structure to model the relationships between the variables.

Logistic regression is generally preferred when the relationship between the predictor variables and the outcome variable is believed to be linear or can be transformed to a linear form.

On the other hand, decision trees are preferred when the relationships between the predictor variables and the outcome variable are non-linear.